# How to dismiss a PopOver after another BarButtonItem has been pressed

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `ViewController` that contains a navigation bar. In this navigation bar, there are 2 `UIBarButtonItem`: A and B.

When A is pressed, another `ViewController` is displayed as a PopOver (segue present as popover).

If I press anywhere on the screen, the popover is dismissed.

The problem is that if I press on B (the other `UIBarButtonItem`) the PopOver is not dismissed...

What should I do to automatically dismiss opened popovers when bar buttons from the navigation bar are pressed?

Comment: can you share the code you have written for Button B press?

Comment: I prepared an example here: https://github.com/appfrancois/PopoverExample
If you click on the bar button A, the popover is displayed. If you click on B the popover is not dismissed.

Comment: did you solve? I have the same issue... after 6 years...